# Socket.io not working during on-mount and only works after refreshing the browser

Tags: server, socket.io, push-notification, client, real-time

I attempted a real-time push notification in my food-ordering web app with a customer and vendor portal. A small real-time notification banner at the corner of screen should appear due to the below 2 actions:

1. when customer place an order, vendor should receive a real-time notification
2. when vendor update the food preparation status, customer should receive a real-time notification

But, the real-time notification is not completely working.

Always, during the first-run, the socket is not working. It only works right after i refresh either one of the client (ie: the customer or vendor sides). I am not sure whether its due to the way i setup my client-server connection or because of the useEffect.

For now i only used .emit and .on along with 2 events named "orderStatusUpdate" and "newOrder". Appreciate if any of you can help me with this issues. I can provide more code snippet or the GitHub repo link if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

===SERVER====

server.ts

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";

import express, { Express } from "express";
import http from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

import cors from "cors"; //enables anyone to use the api
import helmet from "helmet";
import rateLimit from "express-rate-limit";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

dotenv.config();

import auth from "./src/routers/auth";
import items from "./src/routers/items";
import carts from "./src/routers/carts";
import orders from "./src/routers/orders";
import constraint from "./src/routers/constraint";
import image from "./src/routers/image";

//allows api to be called 100 times within 15min interval
const limit = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000, //1min
  max: 1000,
  standardHeaders: true,
  legacyHeaders: false,
});

const app: Express = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
export const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
// io.on("connection", () => {
//   console.log("user connected");
// });

app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(limit);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use("/auth", auth);
app.use("/api", items);
app.use("/api", carts);
app.use("/api", orders);
app.use("/api", constraint);
app.use("/api", image);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001;
// app.listen(PORT, () => {
//   console.log(`server has started on port ${PORT}`);
// });
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server has started on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

orders.ts (using io.emit to trigger client-side useEffect)

```js
import { Request, Response } from "express";
import pool from "../db/db";
import { io } from "../../server";

// orders
.....

const updateOrder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const {
      status,
      rating,
      review,
      is_active,
    }: { status: String; rating: Number; review: String; is_active: Boolean } =
      req.body;

    if ("status" in req.body) {
      const updateStatus = await pool.query(
        "UPDATE orders SET status = $1 WHERE uuid = $2 RETURNING user_id",
        [status, req.params.order_id]
      );

      // use socket.io to trigger the frontend receiver to trigger action of fetching new orderInfo
      io.emit("orderStatusUpdate", updateStatus.rows[0].user_id);
    }
    if ("rating" in req.body) {
      try {
        // Begin a transaction
        await pool.query("BEGIN");

        // Update the order's rating and get the vendor_id
        const updateResult = await pool.query(
          "UPDATE orders SET rating = $1 WHERE uuid = $2 RETURNING vendor_id",
          [rating, req.params.order_id]
        );

        const thisVendorId = updateResult.rows[0].vendor_id;

        // Calculate the average rating
        const avgRatingResult = await pool.query(
          "SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating), 2) FROM orders WHERE vendor_id = $1",
          [thisVendorId]
        );

        const avgRating = avgRatingResult.rows[0].round;

        // Update the vendor's details with the calculated average rating
        await pool.query(
          "UPDATE vendor_details SET rating = $1 WHERE vendor_id = $2",
          [avgRating, thisVendorId]
        );

        // Commit the transaction
        await pool.query("COMMIT");
      } catch (error: any) {
        await pool.query("ROLLBACK");

        console.error(error.message);
        res
          .status(500)
          .json({ error: "An error occurred while updating the rating" });
      }
    }

    if ("review" in req.body) {
      await pool.query("UPDATE orders SET review = $1 WHERE uuid = $2", [
        review,
        req.params.order_id,
      ]);
    }
    if ("is_active" in req.body) {
      await pool.query("UPDATE orders SET is_active = $1 WHERE uuid = $2", [
        is_active,
        req.params.order_id,
      ]);
    }

    res.status(201).json({ status: "ok", msg: "Order updated" });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.json({ status: "error", msg: "Update order failed" });
  }
};

// items_orders
const createItemsOrders = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    // copy item_id, item_price, quantity_ordered and user_note from carts_items; insert order_id
    const cart_id: String = req.body.cart_id;
    const order = await pool.query(
      "INSERT INTO items_orders (item_id, order_id, item_price, quantity_ordered, user_note) SELECT item_id, $1, item_price, quantity_ordered, user_note FROM carts_items WHERE cart_id = $2 AND is_deleted = FALSE RETURNING *",
      [req.params.order_id, cart_id]
    );

    const items_id = order.rows.reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc.push(item.item_id);
      return acc;
    }, []);

    const vendor_id = await pool.query(
      "SELECT vendor_id FROM orders WHERE uuid = $1 ",
      [req.params.order_id]
    );

    io.emit("newOrder", vendor_id.rows[0].vendor_id);

    res.status(201).json({
      msg: "Items_orders created",
      items_orders: order.rows,
      items_id,
    });
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.json({ status: "error", msg: "Create items_orders failed" });
  }
};

.....


export {
  createOrder,
  updateOrder,
  createItemsOrders,
  getItemsOrdersByOrderId,
  getItemsOrdersByVendorId,
  getItemsOrdersByUserId,
  getLastOrderByUserId,
  getActiveOrdersByVendorId,
};
```

====CLIENT=====

socket.tsx (importing and setup io)

```js
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

export const socket = io(import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER);
```

App.tsx (socket.on within useEffect to listen to event from Server)

```js
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import UserContext from "./context/user";
import { socket } from "./socket";

.......

import useFetch from "./hooks/useFetch";
import useFetchImg from "./hooks/useFetchImg";
import {
  OrderInfo,
  Props,
  SnackbarMessage,
  data,
  userInfoType,
} from "./interfaces";

function App() {
  const fetchData = useFetch();
  const fetchDataImg = useFetchImg();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

.......

  // other states
  const [vendorId, setVendorId] = useState<String>("");
  const [vendorInfo, setVendorInfo] = useState<userInfoType>({});

  const [haveActiveOrder, setHaveActiveOrder] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [activeOrderId, setActiveOrderId] = useState<String[]>([]);

  const [cartItemInfo, setCartItemInfo] = useState<Props>({});
  const [orderInfo, setOrderInfo] = useState<OrderInfo>([]);

  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState<string>("");
  const [snackPack, setSnackPack] = useState<readonly SnackbarMessage[]>([]);

.......

  const getCustomerLastOrder = async () => {
    const res: data = await fetchData(
      "/api/orders/items/active/user_id",
      "POST",
      {
        user_id: userId,
      },
      accessToken
    );

    if (res.ok) {
      if (res.data[0].length) {
        setOrderInfo(res.data);

        setHaveActiveOrder(true);
        setActiveOrderId([res.data[0][0].order_id]);
      }
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(res.data));
    }
  };

  const getVendorActiveOrder = async () => {
    const res: data = await fetchData(
      "/api/orders/items/active/vendor_id",
      "POST",
      {
        vendor_id: userId,
      },
      accessToken
    );

    if (res.ok) {
      if (res.data.length) {
        setOrderInfo(res.data);
        setHaveActiveOrder(true);
      } else {
        setOrderInfo([]);
        setHaveActiveOrder(false);
      }
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(res.data));
    }
  };



.........

  // useEff to control instance of sockets received from server to 2
  // was 6-8 times before useEff
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("orderStatusUpdate", (user_id) => {
      if (userId === user_id) {
        console.log("CUSTOMER SOCKET");
        getCustomerLastOrder();
        // activate snackbar for notifications
        setSnackPack((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          { message: "test", key: new Date().getTime() },
        ]);
      }
    });

    socket.on("newOrder", (vendor_id) => {
      if (userId === vendor_id) {
        console.log("VENDOR SOCKET");
        getVendorActiveOrder();
        // activate snackbar for notifications
        setSnackPack((prev) => [
          ...prev,
          { message: "test", key: new Date().getTime() },
        ]);
      }
    });
  }, [socket]);

.......

  return (
    <div>
.........

export default App;
```